# Intel BMC inaccessible during rebooting

Tags: linux, bmc

Is it common that the bmc becomes inaccessible (unable to ping, access from WebUI) when during reboot (sudo reboot)?

It's an Intel Server Board S7200AP.

Comment: It's a shared NIC, right?

Comment: Right, it's in shared NIC mode.

Comment: If shared NIC is the reason, is it possible to keep access to BMC during reboot?
Eg. make linux reboot not to poweroff NIC or something?